# My router destroys my USB disks?

Tags: networking, usb, router, dd-wrt

I got a replacement usb disk 3 weeks ago from the local computershop and it is now destroyed again. It does not appear in Gparted, Windows or anything.

I had the same issue with a new BlackArmor drive, it got broke, but Seagate provided good support.

How come dd-wrt can break 2 flash disks? How does this even work?

Comment: Your router can have no effect on your disks that I know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to imagine that a router is frying your USB sticks. I am to assume your router is one that will host USB devices via a USB port that is ON the router itself? and if so, does the USB stick work at all for this function initially, or does it break it right away? It is very tough to believe that the router is breaking this as because I highly doubt that the USB controller chip actually on the device would be capable of outputting voltage high or strong enough to fry the USB stick. Most of the time it would break the other way around and fry the controller chip. If you insert the USB stick into a linux computer and type `lsusb` for a command in the terminal, does your device even get listed? If it does then potentially the device isnt broken, otherwise you may be SOL. Does DD-WRT firmware version that you flashed on your router explicitly have documentation that says it supports the USB ports for the model router you have? If not you may want to consider finding a version that does or changing routers.